# Process server-side information in nuxt

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a session cookie for my user, for this I make a request to my backend API hoping to return my token, after returning this my token, I need to put it in a cookie to create the session of my user, but next to the token is also returned some information such as the screens that the user can have access, I wanted to know how this is usually done so that this information is not exposed and neither my function to generate the cookie. Some extra information: I'm using typescript; I am using "cookie-universal-nuxt" to handle cookies; I created a plugin of my own in order to treat the information and create the cookie; The request for the API is being executed on the client side;

To solve this problem I found some possible solutions, but I did not do any tests, since most of them seemed to me like "gambiarras"

Edit:

what happens is that I wanted to isolate my session 100%, the way this currently, the session after being generated is very secure, the problem is that there is manipulation on the part of the frontend to mount my cookie, and this occurs on the client side, so in addition to having access to what the backend returns the user also has at his disposal the function that mounts the session cookie, I wanted to isolate this even more, so that it is not possible to manipulate a frontend session and not generate a fake, the cookie is very solid already, I managed to do it in such a way that the session is not manipulable, but I wanted the function that mounts my session to the front not to be exposed to the client, So that it is not possible to see the user information returned by the API or create a fake session, the way I saw that this was possible would be for me to run the request from the server side, hiding the return of my API that is explicit

Question generated with the help of google translate, originally coming from PT-BR

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use nuxt3 it has a build-in cookie dirver that you can use it easily.
2. On your back-end you can set it to work as api not web. seach for jwt auth.
3. you should write in your fetch function to accept json. So your back-end returns no extra infos such as web infos.